# styled-component Grid Areas as Props does't work

Tags: css, styled-components

## Grid area can't be a prop.

=============================

```
export const Code = styled.input<{area?:String}>`
  font-family: Archivo;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  width: 61px;
  height: 19px;
  outline: none;
  border: unset;
  grid-area: ${({area})=>area ? area : ''};
  background-color: transparent;
`;
```

## and it can't be overriden also:

```
 <Code type='text' placeholder='Code' style={{
                    gridArea:"nom code !important"
                }}
```

Comment: hi. What is the mean {area?:string} ?

Comment: Props types for styled components

Answer (score 0):

it was just in front of me hhhhh:

```
 export const Code = styled.input<{area?:string}>` // string type with LowerCase S
      font-family: Archivo;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: 500;
      text-align: center;
      width: 61px;
      height: 19px;
      outline: none;
      border: unset;
      grid-area: ${({area})=>area ? area : 'code'};  // added intial value 
      background-color: transparent;
    `;
```